# How to access Data from another Server not in the same Network

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous, remote-access, server-side

***Hello guys.***

In our actual project we got a **Microsoft Server** accessed **via remotehost**. On this server we installed **xampp** ,**Microsoft SQL Server** and our previously in **ObjectPascal developed program**.

Then we have a **Microsoft SQL Server** at our **Customers**. Then we have **our Application**, programmed in **ObjectPascal**, installed, that works with the SQL-Server and is programmed by our company.

Our **Web-solution** is programmed that it can **work with the database** like our old programm. Furthermore we would like to use the **old program for working locally** and our **web solution for working remotely**. Furthermore the databases on the web-server and at our customer are identical.

Now we have the problem how we can **access the data at our Customers SQL Server**, without the need of complex configuration at our customers network.

Our thoughts were:

- A Web Server at our customer and access the data per AJAX.
- Customers Server permanently asking the web-server if it needs data
- Doing something similar like 'push up notification' sending from the web-server to our customer.
- Maybe synchronising to and from the server?

**We are able to get the public IP-Adress** from our customer and are able to **update it if it change**, so that is no problem. The **only problem** we have is, **how we can access the data from our customer**. Maybe our solutions go to a completely wrong direction, that's why i am asking you guys.

If you could give me some hints, tips and tricks, maybe a link or a technology name  would help me and we would be really gratefull for that.

***I thank you for your time reading this!***

Comment: You should probably move this Question to another site like. Software Engineering, because SO is about solving specific programming problems based on provided code.

Comment: the first question is, you have a web based solution, but its locally at customer, right?

Comment: @AhmedSunny we have an old programm that is locally at the customer and all the data over 20 years is locally there. Now we want to upgrade a remote solution, so we programmed a web based solution. At the moment this solution is deployed on a remote server.

Comment: the problem is security, you cant directly access local server from public IP . your customer servers should allow access from outside, and have a dedicated IP for that,because your customers DB are local . its like I give you my public IP but you cant access my router or my localserver, you are just accessing the Door of you customer but cant go in.for that you have to do local config at customers

Comment: if you want ajax based, you need to have all your customer DBs online, wwhich is not possible in this case, But you can write a script that update your Central DB (for web ) with each clients local data, in this way you are not accessing client but client sending data to you,  a cron job which triggers every day or depends on your requirement

Comment: and you can configure SQL server for each client like [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server/) but as i told you, its a lot of work and you have to do this at each client.

Comment: @AhmedSunny The permanent online is not a problem, we could make this a requirement to have a server that runs permanently anyway. The problem with saving the data on our remote server is, that we have sensitive medical data.

the link you provided, those this work for public network too? because we do this for the local network already. 

In my research i found a technology called web hooks. I think my idea of ajax is like a web hook?

Comment: yes thats also a possibility, you have to create a recieving link for yourside, and then write hook at your client side for each feature or function,  it only needs internet at your client to send you information, and on your side do what you want to do with data